# How to sync drifting audio(s)?

Tags: sync, kdenlive

- One audio source is the camera, (its sound is more for reference 'cause the distance is approximately 10 meters from the source).
- The second audio source is a mixing table getting mics.

The total shooting is around 3 hours on different tapes for the video.
And 1 chunk for the audio.

I have several claps or evident sync during the total event.

I think the camera is not precise, because its sound (and video too) drifts of -5% of the other audio.
Total audio time 3h, video ref 2h50.

My first approach is to treat the sound in Audacity separately first.
But I wonder if Kdenlive or any video editing soft can sync on several references (2 at least)?

Comment: Happens to me anytime I use more than 1 recording method. A laptop compared to a cam, even two different programs on the same laptop, always off by a bit. But 10 minutes on 3 hours is about 9m 40s longer than any difference I've ever seen.